# Indecomposable representation of an acyclic quiver on 3 vertices

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, quiver

I have a question:

> > Suppose we have the quiver \begin{matrix}
> > & 1 & \overset{}{\longrightarrow} && 2   \\
> > && \searrow_{} &  & \downarrow_{} \\
> > & & && 3 
> > \end{matrix} and let us to associate it the following representation $M$: \begin{matrix}
> > & K & \overset{\tiny{\left[\begin{array}{c} \hspace{-0.15cm}1\\0\end{array}\right]}}{\longrightarrow} && K^2   \\
> > && \searrow_{1} &  & \downarrow_{[0 ~ ~ 1]} \\
> > & & && K 
> > \end{matrix}
> >     Now the question is that " Does this representation indecomposable?"

What can I say is no. Because it can be decompose as follows

Let us call the following representation $M_1$:
\begin{matrix}
& K & \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} && K   \\
&& \searrow_{1} &  & \downarrow_{1} \\
& & && K 
\end{matrix}
And let us call the following representation $M_2$:
\begin{matrix}
& 0 & \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} && K   \\
&& \searrow_{0} &  & \downarrow_{0} \\
& & && 0 
\end{matrix}
And then we have $M=M_1\oplus M_2$.

Can someone let me know if I am wrong? Why? And also can someone help me in drawing those diagrams with their vertices shown by a small circle as it is usual in quivers?

Many thanks!

Comment: In $M_1\oplus M_2$ the vertical arrow is $[1\quad 0]$ not $[0 \quad 1]$.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Many thanks for your comment! But I think there is no other way for to get 1 in the crooked arrow? Am I right?

Comment: As Ittay points out, your $M_1\oplus M_2$ doesn't match $M$. Have you tried showing it's indecomposable?

Comment: @anon Many thanks for your comment! No. How can I check it? The only way that I know is to note by intuition that in any case if we want to decompose $M$ then we are not able to keep 1 in the crooked arrow. Can you let me know how to show it?

Comment: @Nikita there aren't too many possibilities for a decomposition due to the very low dimensions of the vertices. You can systematically try them all out and show none is possible. You'll notice that due to the very simple nature of the arrows in $M$, there are really very few options. In particular, how can you get the diagonal arrow to decompose? Either $M_1$ or $M_2$ must have the identity as its diagonal, and the other one must have $0$ as its diagonal. Proceed from there.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Many thanks for your comment! I will do it. So we can conclude that it is indecomposable? Right?

Comment: Check it out and you tell me ;)

Comment: @IttayWeiss Many thanks for your comment! But I even cannot decompose it! Because in the diagram which I go to put 1 in the diagonal arrow will be $\overset{1}{K \to K}$ and the other one has to be $\overset{0}{0 \to 0}$.  And then other arrows in $M_1$ will be $\overset{}{K \to 0}$ and $\overset{}{0 \to K}$  and in $M_2$ will be $\overset{}{0 \to K^2}$ and $\overset{}{K^2 \to 0}$ whom has to be $\tiny{\left[\begin{array}{c} \hspace{-0.15cm}1\\0\end{array}\right]}$ , $[0 ~~ 1]$ , $\tiny{\left[\begin{array}{c} \hspace{-0.15cm}0\\0\end{array}\right]}$ and $[0 ~~0]$, which is not possible!?

Answer (score 2):

You can show that this representation V is indecomposable by computing the idempotents in the endomorphism ring End(V) since there is a theorem that says that a representation V is indecomposable if and only if the only idempotents in End(V) are 0 and 1.

Sketch of proof for the fact that 0 and 1 are the only idempotents in End(V):

1) You take an arbitrary endomorphism f of this representation and compute the relations between its three components (use the definition of a morphism of quiver representations) and see that you do not have much choice.

2) Then you assume that this endomorphism f is an idempotent (f^2 = f). Then its components must be idempotents. If you then think about the possible idempotent linear maps K --> K (which you will need in two of the components), step 1 should do the trick.